# Google bot detecting incorrect links and showing 404 error

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

Hi i changed my CMS and now my webmaster tool showing many 404 errors .Google bot detecting incorrect links .It automatically including category names to all links

Example

It showing 404 error (which definitely doesn't exist)

In Webmaster tool 404 error link

http://www.kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/category/cms/profiles

Link From showing ( this link is also incorrect )

http://www.kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/category/cms/download.php?file=movie_still/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/3858up_and_down_malayalam_movie_photos_003-001.jpg&url=http://www.kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/category/cms/privacy

kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/category/cms/advertise-with-us

correct link is

kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/3858up_and_down_malayalam_movie_photos_003-001

Anyone please help me to fix the issue

Comment: Can you tell us if and how the links are being generated, are they being generated on the fly from a database, if so are the database queries pulling back the correct information? The more information you can supply the better an answer can be given.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply . this link is only showing in Google webmaster tool 404 error page .I have checked full website but i don't find any link like this .I think google bot automatically detecting .  in this link http://www.kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/category/cms/profiles  . from category/cms/profiles is automatically added .I this is added from navigation bar names .Is this issue related to my navigation bar ?

Answer (score 0):

This could be temporary issue. Please update your sitemap.xml and robots.txt files.

Comment: This issue is started to 3 months before .Is this issue is related to canonical link or script error Because navigationbar catogeries are automatically adding to this links

Comment: Canonical links are used to let search engines know that it's same page for two different links. e.g. page.html?lang=en and page.html?lang=es. Are the links being referred from a external source? Make sure you don't have any of the old links on your sitemaps, footers and content.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you change url formats on a production site, you should always make redirects from old urls to new urls.

Where you do it depends on your project. The easiers is in a .htaccess, but if you need to check for example a database do find the new url you can do it in php (or your programming language) and do a redirect in the script.
If it's a permanent redirect you should use 301 as redirect code:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

Comment: I already update sitemap etc.. This issue started 3 months before . 

404 error link is 

http://www.kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/category/cms/profiles

in this link category/cms/profiles is detecting from navigation bar and footer . I don't know how google detecting this link , my CMS is not generating any link like this 


correct link is 

http://www.kerala9.com/movie/up-down-mukalil-oralundu/still/625/3858up_and_down_malayalam_movie_photos_003-001


Is this issue is related to canonical link or script issue ?

Comment: I think you can find information in google webmaster tools where they found pointing to the 404 page.